# Php file encryption methods. Does something simple exist?

Tags: php, file, encryption

It's seems that there isn't any pleasant way to encrypt a file in php.

The built in methods of php, mcrypt, aren't very portable as most servers don't support them.

Command line encryption tools are like ugly hacks.

There's encryption for strings which is nice, but if we want to encrypt a file it doesn't help very much especially for someone else to unencrypt it.

Other encryption tools require public keys, key rings, private keys, blood sample... These seem much too complicated for just encrypting a file.

It seems that we should just have a simple function for PHP that could work like so:

```
$crypt = new Crypt();
$crypt->encryptFile("Password1245!", 'secret_file.txt', 'encrypted_file.txt');
$crypt->decryptFile("Password1245!", 'encrypted_file.txt', 'original_file.txt');
```

Any one have any ideas? I'm pulling out hair!

EDIT:
Another thing I should add, for the end user to be able to decrypt the file with ease.

**Basically I'm trying to find something that can replace a password protected zip file**

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [PEAR encryption packages](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=6&catname=Encryption).  They don't all rely on mcrypt - for example [Crypt_Blowfish](http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_Blowfish/docs/latest/Crypt_Blowfish/Crypt_Blowfish.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having the mcrypt extension installed, this code should do it:

```
function Encrypt($string, $key)
{
    if (extension_loaded('mcrypt') === true)
    {
        return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, substr($key, 0, mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)), trim($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
    }

    return false;
}

function Decrypt($string, $key)
{
    if (extension_loaded('mcrypt') === true)
    {
        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, substr($key, 0, mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)), base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)));
    }

    return false;
}

function Encrypt_File($source, $destination, $key)
{
    if (extension_loaded('mcrypt') === true)
    {
        if (is_file($source) === true)
        {
            $source = file_get_contents($source);

            if (file_put_contents($destination, Encrypt($source, $key), LOCK_EX) !== false)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function Decrypt_File($source, $destination, $key)
{
    if (extension_loaded('mcrypt') === true)
    {
        if (is_file($source) === true)
        {
            $source = file_get_contents($source);

            if (file_put_contents($destination, Decrypt($source, $key), LOCK_EX) !== false)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to base64 encode the contents of a file? There is nothing wrong with binary contents for files. base64 encoding increases data size by 33%

Comment: I don't like to have new lines, since they might not be copied if I need to use the encrypted data in a copy/paste scenario, but yes it still works without base64 encoding/decoding.

Answer (score -3):

what about simple xor?

```
function Crypt($source, $key)
{
 $rv='';
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($source);$i++)
 {
  $rv.=chr(ord($source[$i]) ^ ord($key[$i%strlen($key)]));
 }
 return $rv;
}
```

=> Crypt(Crypt('aaa','key'),'key') returns 'aaa'.

EDIT: of course, you should use

```
file_put_contents(Crypt(file_get_contents('file'), 'key'));
```

for file read+write :]

Comment: That's a nice algorithm, but the problem comes when the end user needs to decrypt it. Short of writing a windows app to decode there probably isn't an easy way for them to decode it. I'll probably use what you've got here in other projects, it's nice clean and simple.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare crypt()
...
Fatal error: Call to undefined function asc()
...
NULL
...?

Comment: @SeanDowney: according to Yossarian it should encrypt and decrypt strings, the only problem is that I can't get it to work even after fixing the bugs. =\

Comment: Although it looks like an encrypted file, this is not encryption and it should not be used for data that needs to stay secret.

Comment: +1, but its might still be useful for other not so sensitive purposes.

Comment: sorry, my faults, i didnt read that after myself. in fact, if the key is as long as the data, it is the only unbreakable encryption ;-)

Comment: Umm, pretty much *any* encryption is unbreakable if you encrypt 1GB of data with a 1GB key.

Comment: It is only unbreakable if the key is as long as the data AND if the key is ONLY EVER USED ONCE.
Use the same key twice and the key has effectively become public.

Comment: The key also has to be random.

If the key is repeated, this algorithm is a type of Vigenère cipher, which isn't very hard to crack:
  http://www.simonsingh.net/The_Black_Chamber/vigenere_cracking.html
  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=161722

Comment: Xor fails when a = b ie. a ^ a = 0

Comment: @evandrix, and where is the fail? When you apply the same key again,  a^a^a = a.

Answer (score -3):

Yossarian's Crypt() function fixed:

```
function _Crypt($source, $key)
{
    $result = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($source); $i++)
    {
        $result .= chr(ord($source[$i]) ^ ord($key[$i % strlen($key)]));
    }

    return $result;
}

_Crypt('aaa', 'key'); // 
_Crypt(_Crypt('aaa', 'key'), 'key'); // aaa
```

Comment: Is that XOR? That's a so-called "kid sister encryption", i.e. only useful for hiding stuff from your kid sister. (yeah, you could use OTP and stuff, but that's far from simple)

Comment: This is not useful in a security context at all. _Crypt is a misleading function name. It is not encryption, it is obfuscation at best.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and so is Yossarian (see the post below), I just fixed a couple of errors in his code, why am I being voted down? blah :P

Comment: if the key is as long as the message, the algorithm is perfect, so this answer is quite interesting, indeed!