# general file encryption

Tags: php, ssl

I was wondering if someone could give me some advice on file encryption, I am currently building an intranet and one of the features that it needs to have is for users to send files to other users, http://www.mailbigfile.com/ is an example of what I am looking to achieve. This is currently being done over SSL and I use PHP for validating the file type etc before being uploaded. The only issue I am having is that my employers want me to encrypt the files before being uploaded, they also want each uploaded file to be encrypted with a random salt as an additional security measure. One of my main concerns is that the file type is not really restricted so it could be anything from a jpeg to a word document and so far I have found it difficult to encrypt word and pdf documents with php. So i was wondering if someone could give me advice on the following

1.Do you need to encrypt files if you are using an SSL and restricting direct access to the directory

2.Should I be using php for encrypting e.g. MCRYPT or is there an alternative. From a previous thread someone recommended using PEAR

[Php file encryption methods. Does something simple exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805686/php-file-encryption-methods-does-something-simple-exist)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1) Not for the transfer but I think the point here is to store the file in a secure way, so that even if you have gained somehow access to the file you can not use it without know its encryption and salt. You would generate the salt and save it in the db together with a reference to the file. The idea is that if someone gains access to the file but not the db the files will be useless because the attacker does not know anything about the file. When somebody requests the file for download and who is authorized you'll need to decrypt it before sending it to the client. Guess thats what your requirements are?

2) I would do a fallback, use mcrypt functions from the modules if available if not fall back to PEAR because pear will be slower than the modules. But you said it is an intranet so it should be easy to add the mcrypt module.

Comment: Thanks for the response burzum, yes I would need to decrypt the file before the authorized user downloaded the file, what i had originally planned was to open the file contents and overwrite them with the encrypted info before uploading and reverse this when downloading the file but file_get_contents doesn't seem to like formats like .pdf and .docx

Comment: file_get_contents() does not care about the data formats. There must be another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting every file *before* upload means it has to happen on the client computer. This must therefore be done either with a separate program (say, GNU PG) or in the browser, for example [AES via Javascript](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) (or a Java applet, or Flash that do the same).

Encrypting files for the transfer via SSH is not necessary, as the protocol already does that. However, while the file will be safe "on the wire", the file will be readable by anyone having access to the recipient machine (and the server). If that is a problem, you **must** encrypt the files.

The biggest challenge is communicating encryption keys from sender to recipient in a safe manner. This is entirely non-trivial, and if done wrong makes the entire process of multi-layer encrypting and adding lots of salt useless. For example, if the encryption key is on the server where the recipient downloads the files (via SSH), then anyone with sufficient access to the server (an administrator, or an intruder) can just decrypt the files with the keys stored there, making all encryption useless. Public key cryptography is one remedy for that problem. Did I mention GNU PG earlier?

As for "salt", this is the wrong term, you probably meant "initialization vector" (salt is for hash functions, not for encryption).

The solution to the "need individual IV" requirement is rather easy: Generate one or two blocks worth of pseudorandom data (also add some real random or not-random-but-variant data, e.g. something like `nanotime` if you can) on the client computer. For AES, two blocks would be 32 bytes (256 bits), which is incidentially the output size of several modern cryptographic hash functions.
This makes it possible to e.g. concatenate 10-20 pseudorandom characters (even from a poor generator) with the nanosecond timestamp, `SELECT RAND();` from a nearby SQL server, the time it took the server to answer, and the 5 last viewed sites from the browser's history, feed all that into SHA-256, and use the output as a practically unpredictable initialization vector.
After the file has been transferred to the recipient, decrypt it, and ignore the first 32 bytes.